# No internet access to apache home webserver

Tags: apache2, webserver, port-forwarding

I am setting up a webserver from home, mostly to have a nextcloud server. I have the website all setup and running on a LAMP stack. Now i need to port forward my virtualhost. However my ISP blocks port 80 so I went on `canyouseeme.org` and they dont block port 90. Therefore i setup my port forwarding in my router 90,90 both protocols and ip adress. Went into `apache2.conf` added `NameVirtualHost *:90`. Then in my `domain.com.conf` file i changed the `<VirtualHost *:80>` to `<VirtualHost *:90>` . And finaly in the `ports.conf` file i added the line `Listening 90`.

However i still dont have access from an outside computer. Have I overlooked or missed something?

## Update 1:

When i run the command `sudo lsof -i tcp:90 | egrep LISTEN` my output is:

```
apache2   739     root    8u  IPv6  50229      0t0  TCP *:90 (LISTEN)
apache2 16275 www-data    8u  IPv6  50229      0t0  TCP *:90 (LISTEN)
apache2 16276 www-data    8u  IPv6  50229      0t0  TCP *:90 (LISTEN)
apache2 16277 www-data    8u  IPv6  50229      0t0  TCP *:90 (LISTEN)
apache2 16278 www-data    8u  IPv6  50229      0t0  TCP *:90 (LISTEN)
apache2 16279 www-data    8u  IPv6  50229      0t0  TCP *:90 (LISTEN)
apache2 16280 www-data    8u  IPv6  50229      0t0  TCP *:90 (LISTEN)
```

## Update 2:

When i ran nmap from an outside computer I get on port 90 `I have Discovered open port 90/tcp on my-public-ip` and `90/tcp open dnsix syn-ack ttl 253` and on port 80 i get `80/tcp filtered http no-response.`

However I was able to get access to the site content from outside using `my.ip.add.res:90`. Hoever It only sends over the html content, no css. and i cant access it through the domain name.

Comment: Will you edit your question and add the output of `sudo lsof -i tcp:90 | egrep LISTEN`?

Comment: @L.D.James Done

Comment: What is the made and model of your router.  I'll check the specs to see how to verify there isn't a default firewall setting blocking the access.

Comment: What happens if you try http://127.0.0.1/ in your browser on your webserver ? (e.g. with lynx txt browser) You can also test with "telnet localhost 90". Also, Apache2 has a default vhost enabled. Did you disable that one, and enable your domain.com.conf with a2ensite ?

Comment: @L.D.James  Its a buffalo dd-wrt nxt

Comment: @albert j the website works locally inside my network with the domain name and ip address, i also did disable the default vhost and enabled the domain.com.conf with a2ensite

Answer (score 0):

With Nginx it is easy to change ports per vhost, but with Apache, my impression is that you need to also edit the ports.conf file, for example :

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

and then restart Apache.

Comment: I did change the ports.conf, i added `Listening 90`

Answer (score 0):

Include the port number in your url that you're using to access your server. eg. http://www.example.com:90 since the default port your browser will be looking for is 80 for http and 443 for https.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work

Comment: Can you run "nmap -vv -PN your-public-ip-address-here" from outside your home to see whether port 90 is completely closed or not ? Just to see whether the portforwarding on your router is working.

Comment: Sorry for the delay I wasnt able to get my hands on a pc outside my network. So I was able to run nmap and on port 90 I have `Discovered open port 90/tcp on my-public-ip` and `90/tcp    open     dnsix                syn-ack ttl 253` and on port 80 i get `80/tcp    filtered http                 no-response`